# Does having a sponsor take care of acommodation weaken my visa application to Australia

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, australia, business-travel

I am an Indian Citizen living and applying for an Australian business visitor visa from India.

A business agent has agreed to take care of my accommodation during the stay and  though this may be common for family visits, I am concerned if having a sponsor gives the immigration authorities any indication that I am not in a position to afford a commercial accomodation, which is actually not true.

Since I will really be staying in the accommodation provided by the Agent I want to be honest about this, however if booking an accomodation in a hotel and mentioning that as my primary arrangement for stay would decrease the chances of my visa application being rejected, I am prepared to do that.

Note: Since I am one of the directors I used "I" interchangeably with my company

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're visiting Australia on business for your company, and your host, a different company, is paying for your accommodation?  That strikes me as rather unusual... unless you're **working** for the host, which would violate the terms of your visa.

The normal situation is that you're in Australia for meetings, exploring business opportunities etc, in which case it's expected that the company sending you pays.  In any case it would be odd for you, personally, to pay, unless you're a one-man consultancy or something.

Comment: Its not a one man consultancy but I am one of the directors, the Agent paying for accomodation did feel to me as strange and hence the question.

Comment: The real thing is that we both work together and my visit enhances business vaue for both our companies and that is the reason for the host company is agreeing to accommodate me, but I think its best to keep this transaction off the records and just get my company to sponsor the entire trip on paper